# How to search from two table in mysql php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a search box in my PHP file. but its searches from only one table name "countries"
but I have another table "continent" I want my search box to get results from both tables "countries" & "continent". currently, it looks like this[my search box][1]

```html
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
 
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 
if(isset($_REQUEST["term"])){
    // Prepare a select statement
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM countries WHERE name LIKE ?";
          
         
    
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_term);
        
        // Set parameters
        $param_term = $_REQUEST["term"] . '%';
        
        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            
            // Check number of rows in the result set
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                // Fetch result rows as an associative array
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                   
                    echo '<img src="'.$row['image'].' "width="85px" height="85px" >';
                    echo '<p><a href="deteles.php?ID='. $row['id'] .'" target="_blank">'. $row['name']. '</a></p>';
                   
                    
                }
            } else{
                echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
            }
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
        }
    }
     
    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
 
// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

and this is my tables[table1][2]
[table3][3]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>PHP Live MySQL Database Search</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        font-family: Arail, sans-serif;
    }
    /* Formatting search box */
    .search-box{
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .search-box input[type="text"]{
        height: 32px;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .result{
        position: absolute;        
        z-index: 999;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .search-box input[type="text"], .result{
        width: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    /* Formatting result items */
    .result p{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 7px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        margin-top: -60px;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-left: 94px;
    }
    .result p:hover{
        background: #f2f2f2;
    }
    .result img{
        float: left;
        float: unset;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    .result p a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
        /* Get input value on change */
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
        if(inputVal.length){
            $.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                resultDropdown.html(data);
            });
        } else{
            resultDropdown.empty();
        }
    });
    
    // Set search input value on click of result item
    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
        $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
        $(this).parent(".result").empty();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="search-box">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search country..." />
        <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

These are my two PHP files.

Comment: Combine database tables via JOIN

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Searching Multiple Tables (SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814522/searching-multiple-tables-sql)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UNION. The only condition is column count should match in both the queries. Here is an example

```
SELECT id, name, 'country' FROM countries WHERE name LIKE '%America%' 
UNION
SELECT id, name, 'continent' FROM continents WHERE name LIKE '%America%';
```

Comment: Displaying 'continent' in a column called 'country' seems a little perverse